# Cordova-keyboard not work on iOS and displays a dark area above the keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

I’m developing my first app with framework7. I had to run it for iPhone 6 and the iOS platform version is iOS 4.5.5.
I’m building the app with 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1). However the keyboard of the iPhone overlays the input that I want to compile, especially with inputs which are at the end of the page.
To solve the issue I installed the cordova-plugin-keyboard v. 1.2.0.
But when I open the keyboard to compile the input a black area appears above the keyboard.
This is the issue

[image: issue]

It looks like a Cordova bug. How can I solve it? if I can't use this plugin, how can I solve the cause that keyboard overlaps the input?

Thank you in advance